# How does one find the internal width of a number type input after it has been rendered?

Tags: html, css

I have an html number input with text align set to center. I want to center text above and below so that it lines up with the text in the input field; however, some browsers add up and down arrows that shift the center of the text in the input field. Is there a way for me to calculate by how much the center is shifted at runtime?

Comment: Have you try it before?

Comment: @IanMustafa I couldn't find any property that that has the information I'm looking for, so I can't try it. I was was wondering if there is such a property or another way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<input type="number">` element is *expected* to be rendered differently in different browsers and with different settings. It is expected to provide *some* user interface for entering a number, and only a number, with the constraints specified by other attributes of the elements. Thus, you cannot know what it looks like or control that, unless a browser provides an API for that.

So if you wish to align the number entered by the user up with some other elements, use `<input type="text">` instead and perform checks on the data format with the `pattern` attribute and/or JavaScript (in addition to server-side checks, of course).

Comment: What a shame, because I wanted all the features of the `<input type="number">`.